# How to override vendor\magento\module-sales-sequence\Model\Sequence.php

Tags: magento2, module, sequence

I want to override file in vendor\magento\module-sales-sequence\Model\Sequence.php

> Magentsales\Modulesequence\registration.php

```
<?php
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
 'Magentsales_Modulesequence',
 __DIR__
 );
```

> Magentsales\Modulesequence\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string">%s%'.04d%s</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<preference for="Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence" type="Magentsales\Modulesequence\Model\SalesSequence\Sequence" />
</config>
```

> Magentsales\Modulesequence\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="Magentsales_Modulesequence" setup_version="1.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

> Magentsales\Modulesequence\Model\SalesSequence\Sequence.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Magentsales\Modulesequence\Model\SalesSequence; 
 class Sequence extends \Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence
 {  
 public function getCurrentValue()
{
  if (!isset($this->lastIncrementId)) {
        return null;
    }
    $prefix = "HLS".date("-y");

    return sprintf($this->pattern, $prefix, $this->calculateCurrentValue(), $this->meta->getActiveProfile()->getSuffix());
   }
 }
```

i edited in file Sequnce.php file in "getCurrentValue()" for rename order and invoice number but it's not getting. Please let me know any thing wrong in module?

Comment: Try adding sequence in "Magentsales\Modulesequence\etc\module.xml" file for core module like this
```
<sequence>
            <module name="Magento_SalesSequence"/>
</sequence>
```
within <module> tag

Comment: There is a private function in that file calculateCurrentValue() which wouldn't be called from your function so you need to add that function also in your overided file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify **Magentsales\Modulesequence\Model\SalesSequence\Sequence.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magentsales\Modulesequence\Model\SalesSequence;

use Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Meta;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection as AppResource;

class Sequence extends \Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $lastIncrementId;

    /**
     * @var Meta
     */
    private $meta;

    /**
     * @var false|\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $pattern;

    /**
     * @param Meta $meta
     * @param AppResource $resource
     * @param string $pattern
     */
    public function __construct(
        Meta $meta,
        AppResource $resource,
        $pattern = self::DEFAULT_PATTERN
    ) {
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection('sales');
        $this->pattern = $pattern;
        parent::__construct($meta, $resource, $pattern);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentValue()
    {
        if (!isset($this->lastIncrementId)) {
            return null;
        }

        $prefix = "HLS".date("-y");
        return sprintf(
            $this->pattern,
            $prefix,
            $this->calculateCurrentValue(),
            $this->meta->getActiveProfile()->getSuffix()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve next value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNextValue()
    {
        $this->connection->insert($this->meta->getSequenceTable(), []);
        $this->lastIncrementId = $this->connection->lastInsertId($this->meta->getSequenceTable());
        return $this->getCurrentValue();
    }

    /**
     * Calculate current value depends on start value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function calculateCurrentValue()
    {
        return ($this->lastIncrementId - $this->meta->getActiveProfile()->getStartValue())
            * $this->meta->getActiveProfile()->getStep() + $this->meta->getActiveProfile()->getStartValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sohel , it's working thank you

Comment: Hello, is their any way i can append a prefix to increment id to order from here ?

Answer (score 2):

**please try this code:-**

> CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Sequence" />
</config>
```

> CompanyName/ModuleName/Model/Sequence.php

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection as AppResource;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface;
use Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Meta;


class Sequence extends \Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $lastIncrementId;

    /**
     * @var Meta
     */
    private $meta;

    /**
     * @var false|\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * @param Meta $meta
     * @param AppResource $resource
     * @param string $pattern
     */
    public function __construct(
        Meta $meta,
        AppResource $resource,
        $pattern = \Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence::DEFAULT_PATTERN
    ) {
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection('sales');
        $this->pattern = $pattern;
    }

 public function getCurrentValue()
{
  if (!isset($this->lastIncrementId)) {
        return null;
    }
    $prefix = "HLS".date("-y");

    return sprintf($this->pattern, $prefix, $this->calculateCurrentValue(), $this->meta->getActiveProfile()->getSuffix());

 }

}
```